# Vertical alignment of first multicolumn entry

Tags: vertical-alignment, multicolumn

I have the following multicolumn:

```
\begin{multicols}{3}
    \scriptsize{
        \begin{align*}
            P_B & =  \text{Bemessungs-Bruchlast}\\
            P_V & =  \text{Versagenslast (zulässige Last)}\\
            R_C & =  \text{Scherfestigkeit}\\
            d_R & =  \text{Nietschaftdurchmesser } \\
            & = d \text{ (Pass- und Blindniet)}\\
            & = d + 0,05 \si{\milli\metre} \text{ geschlagener Niet}\\
            m   & =  \text{Schnittigkeit}\\
            n   & =  \text{Nietzahl}\\
        \end{align*}
        \begin{align*}
            P_B & =  \text{Bemessungs-Bruchlast}\\
            e   & =  \text{Randabstand)}\\
            d   & =  \text{Bohrungsdurchmesser}\\
            s   & =  \text{Blechdicke } \\
            R_C & =  \text{Scherfestigkeit (Blech)}\\
            n   & =  \text{Nietzahl}\\
                & \\
                & \\
        \end{align*}    
        \begin{align*}
            P_B & =  \text{Bemessungs-Bruchlast}\\
            e   & =  \text{Randabstand)}\\
            d   & =  \text{Bohrungsdurchmesser}\\
            s   & =  \text{Blechdicke } \\
            R_C & =  \text{Scherfestigkeit (Blech)}\\
            R_M & =  \text{Bruchfestigkeit (Zug)}\\
            R_{p0,2} & = \text{Dehngrenze}\\
        \end{align*}}
\end{multicols}
```

For some reason the first column isn't aligned with the second and third column, does anybody have an idea why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `minipages`:

```
\documentclass[parskip=half-]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath,siunitx}   
\begin{document}

\footnotesize
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\linewidth}
\begin{align*}
        P_B & =  \text{Bemessungs-Bruchlast}\\
        P_V & =  \text{Versagenslast (zulässige Last)}\\
        R_C & =  \text{Scherfestigkeit}\\
        d_R & =  \text{Nietschaftdurchmesser } \\
        & = d \text{ (Pass- und Blindniet)}\\
        & = d + 0,05 \si{\milli\metre} \text{ geschlagener Niet}\\
        m   & =  \text{Schnittigkeit}\\
        n   & =  \text{Nietzahl}\\
\end{align*}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\linewidth}
        \begin{align*}
        P_B & =  \text{Bemessungs-Bruchlast}\\
        e   & =  \text{Randabstand)}\\
        d   & =  \text{Bohrungsdurchmesser}\\
        s   & =  \text{Blechdicke } \\
        R_C & =  \text{Scherfestigkeit (Blech)}\\
        n   & =  \text{Nietzahl}\\
        & \\
        & \\
        \end{align*}    
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\linewidth}
        \begin{align*}
        P_B & =  \text{Bemessungs-Bruchlast}\\
        e   & =  \text{Randabstand)}\\
        d   & =  \text{Bohrungsdurchmesser}\\
        s   & =  \text{Blechdicke } \\
        R_C & =  \text{Scherfestigkeit (Blech)}\\
        R_M & =  \text{Bruchfestigkeit (Zug)}\\
        R_{p0,2} & = \text{Dehngrenze}\\
        \end{align*}
\end{minipage}

\normalsize
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This solution isn't centering my text the way that multicols does though, is there a way to fix this?

Comment: what do you mean with "centering the text"

Comment: Ah, understood. It is a problem with the fontsize. `\footnotesize` is a bit too big. Use `\scriptsize` instead

Comment: I think I fixed it, it was an issue related to the use of the itemize environment (that I didn't include in the original post). \centering centers my text vertically now. Thanks though!

Comment: This solution still gives me a different problem concerning the vertical alginment once I integrated the other terms, but I think it deserves a new thread.

Comment: yes, because I do not understand what you mean :-)